# Quartz setup for Angular 4 Application

Tags: angular, quartz

I have an application in Angular 4 which is upgraded from AngularJS. I want to move the Quartz scheduler I have in AngularJS also in Angular 4 code.But the "SchedulerRepository.Instance" is returning null though I have given the same web.config file. Please help.

Comment: Angular is JavaScript code executing in your browser. Quartz is a Java library scheduling jobs on your server. They have absolutely nothing related to each other. To make it clear, the fact that you use AngularJS or Angular is as relevant to Quartz as the fact that you prefer dogs or cats.

Comment: And of course, we have no way of telling why unknown code is returning null.